# Quality profile weirdness (active/inactive rules) after sonarqube upgrade 6.3.1

Tags: sonarqube

I have upgraded sonarqube server from 6.2 to 6.3.1 and since then I see a weird behaviour regarding the quality profile (it might have occurred before, it is only now I see it).

When I click on the Quality Profile *SonarWay* (Java) I see

[image]

so it seems, that all rules are inactive.

When I click *Activate More* I see the following

[image]

so it looks, that there are rules are active (I assume due to the "Deactivate" option").

But when switching in the left bar to "active" under *Quality Profile* results in this

[image]

so clearly, no rules are active.

What is the second image then showing, what does the "Deactivate" mean, although it is inactive ?

How could this happen that suddenly all rules seem to be inactivated ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This specific behaviour is a common symptom of a corrupted Elastic Search index (no longer in sync with SonarQube database).

## Solution

Rebuild the SonarQube ElasticSearch index:

- stop your SonarQube server
- delete the ElasticSearch index @ *sonar_install_dir/data/es*
- start your SonarQube server

(reminder: *ElasticSearch* is a search engine used by SonarQube to index issues, rules etc. so that it can access this data rapidly without having to query the database all the time, see [SonarQube Architecture](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE56/Architecture+and+Integration))

## Root-cause

Why did that happen ? A common case is an ElasticSearch index not being properly rebuilt after upgrading and/or changing database. Here's a typical scenario: you first start SonarQube on embedded H2 database, experiment a bit with it, then plug it to a full-fledged database. If the ElasticSearch index does not get scratched/rebuilt in between, then the index gets corrupted as the database/dataset it used to be in synch with just changed all of the sudden.

FYI there's an improvement planned to handle this more gracefully: [SONAR-5681](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-5681) .

Note: independently from above solution, do not take ElasticSearch index rebuild as a lightweight operation that should be performed regularly. SonarQube does self-manage its ElasticSearch index, so any issue must be investigated first.

Comment: your scenario is exactly what I did.. I think I got confused because of the sentence on the update page "Install the plugins compatible with your version of SonarQube.[...] Note that simply copying plugins from the old server to the new is not recommended; incompatible plugins could cause startup errors." - so my assumption was to start the new server and install plugins and at that point it was still pointing to the H2.

Comment: not work in sonarqube 6.7, I even unzip a new copy and delete old installation. any idea?